# Debezium docker with connect table.include.list not working

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using this example to sync elasticsearch with mssql https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/unwrap-smt#elasticsearch-sink

I'm running debezium 1.5 with this mssql connection setting:

```
{
    "name": "Test-connector", 
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector", 
        "database.hostname": "192.168.1.234", 
        "database.port": "1433", 
        "database.user": "user", 
        "database.password": "pass", 
        "database.dbname": "Test", 
        "database.server.name": "MyServer",
        "table.include.list": "dbo.TEST_A",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", 
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.testA"
    }
}
```

According to debezium https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/sqlserver.html
table.include.list

> An optional comma-separated list of regular expressions that match fully-qualified table identifiers for tables that you want Debezium to capture; any table that is not included in table.include.list is excluded from capture. Each identifier is of the form schemaName.tableName. By default, the connector captures all non-system tables for the designated schemas. Must not be used with table.exclude.list.

When I run this connector kafka doesn't respect table.exclude.list. Listing the topics shows all tables has been captured. The TEST_A topic is also there. I also tried "snapshot.include.collection.list": "Test.dbo.TEST_A" without result. What am I missing?

Comment: What is dbo in dbo.TEST_A? you have specified **"database.dbname": "Test"**. So, "table.include.list" should be "Test.TEST_A".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out it should be table.whitelist instead of table.include.list. Not sure why though.